# Does Elastic APM support Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-cloud-stream, apm, distributed-tracing

I am very new to Elastic APM and not sure how it can support different frameworks. I can see that from the documentation APM supports Spring Boot. I have tested a Spring Boot application with the APM and it looks promising. I was wondering if APM supports Spring Cloud Stream as well. Spring Cloud Stream provides Event Driven Architecture by using Spring Boot and messaging middleware. Middleware can be Kafka, RabbitMQ, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with what is Elastic APM, but if it says it supports Spring Boot, then it means it supports any spring-boot-based framework which Spring Cloud Stream is.